# Applying for a UK spouse visa, how long should we say we are going to stay?

Tags: eu-spouses, uk-visa

I'm French, working in the UK. My wife is Chinese, living in China. We have been doing long distance relationship, now we are married and she is going to apply for the spouse visa (EEA family permit) to join the UK.

On the visa application, **they ask how long she is going to stay**. The reality is we don't know. At least 6 months, but it could be 1 year, 2 years, ... we don't have a good idea. N.B: I'm under a permanent work contract.

How will our answer to the question "how long are you going to stay" influence our chance to get the visa?

We are thinking that if we say "3 years or more" they are going to think "this application is for people who want to immigrate definitely" and have less chance to get it.
And if we say "6 months/1 year" they are going to think "for such a short time they should rather not bother apply".

Comment: I'll offer this as an opinion, hence the comment. Wouldn't the answer be 'permanently?' Even if the visa is for for 2.5 years, she's applying for settlement as a spouse. You can add exactly what you noted here, that you have a permanent position in the UK etc. Shortly before the end of the visa, she can apply to remain in the UK with family (and do it while she's in the UK).

Answer (score 1):

Under the circumstances, wouldn't the answer be 'permanently?' Even if the visa is for for 2.5 years, she's applying for settlement as a spouse. You can add exactly what you noted here, that you have a permanent position in the UK etc. Shortly before the end of the visa, she can [apply to remain in the UK with family](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/608678/FLR_M_-04-17.pdf) (and do it while she's in the UK).